# Запись в канал С++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Нахожусь в полном унынии, прочитал в книге где все вроде бы правильно, как писать и читать из канала. Вот мой пример:

Есть главная функция которая создает два потока, первый поток создает именованный канал и пишет в него свои вычисления, и отправляет это все во второй поток по этому самому каналу.
Проблема возникла на этапе записи в канал первым потоком.

```
DWORD WINAPI Tread(LPVOID param)
{
...

wchar_t *PName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\TransmitPipe";
HANDLE hPipe;

hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(PName,PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |PIPE_WAIT,PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,4096,4096,0,NULL);

DWORD byteCnt, byteWrt;              //Число байт который пишутся в канал, число реально записанных байт в канал
char *PipeStr = new char[Length]     //Строка которую передадим в канал
PipeStr = ...чему то там, что вычисляет поток...
PipeStr[Length] = '\0';

byteCnt = Length  //Число байт которые будем записывать, сколько длинна char столько и запишем

BOOL Success;

Success = WriteFile(hPipe, PipeStr, byteCnt, &byteWrt, NULL);
if(!Success) {std::cout<<"Pipe creation is failed    "<<GetLastError();}
}
```

Вот он мне и пишет этот самый "Pipe creation is failed" и выдает рядом 536 ошибку по ф-ии GetLastError.

В чем проблема, из-за чего ошибка? (Пишу в VC)

Я понимаю, что где то конкретно накосячил, но так уж вышло, что впервые работаю с каналами.

Comment: А предупреждений (warnings) при трансляции никаких не выдавало? И какого типа должен быть параметр Pname?

Comment: char *PipeStr = new char[Length]
    ...
    PipeStr[Length] = '\0';

Оригинально! Ну правильно, зачем строкам нулевой символ :))

Comment: > Какой лояльный к ошибкам компилятор

это вы в 1с, наверное, не программировали...

Comment: @mega криминала в присвоении PipeStr адреса массив char не вижу, а вот запись нуля за пределами выделенного массива -- это уже нехорошо.

@BlackOverlord заглянул в msdn на предмет ошибки 536 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

     ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING
     536 (0x218)
     Waiting for a process to open the other end of the pipe

Какая у Вас нетерпеливая программа...

Comment: >это вы в 1с, наверное, не программировали...

Программировали, только здесь речь о `VS`, а не об `1с`

>криминала в присвоении PipeStr адреса массив char не вижу

И я не вижу :)

Comment: @mega варнингов не было, все по госту.  @alexlz  параметр Pname в прототипе функции должен быть типа LPTWSTR, но в примере подают как и у меня обычный чар.

Comment: Ну во-первых не char, а wchar_t (приложение, как я понимаю, unicode'ное), а вот с какого примера Вы рисовали свою программу -- это интересно. Потому как посылаете Вы свою PipeStr непонятно кому, о чём Вам винды и пытаются сказать.

Comment: @alexlz Спасибо, вы были правы насчет посыла строки в никуда) Я по глупости своей написав опубликованный кусок кода, решил проверить его запустив программу не позаботившись о заплатке в виде приемника данных) Вопрос закрыт.